# It's a stack-related parenthesis check, but I can't solve it

Tags: c, stack

I don't know how to solve the stack problems.

If there is an incomplete parenthesis in the middle, the problem is that the i at the end of the sentence is printed unconditionally.

I want the " i " in between to be printed if I don't complete the expression in parentheses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STACK_SIZE 100

typedef char element;
typedef struct {
    element data[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int top;
}StackType;

void init_stack(StackType* s) {
    s->top = -1;
}

int is_empty(StackType* s) {
    return (s->top == -1);
}

int is_full(StackType* s) {
    return (s->top == (MAX_STACK_SIZE - 1));
}

void push(StackType* s, element item) {
    if (is_full(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack Flow Error\n");
        return;
    }
    
    else {
        s->data[++(s->top)] = item;
    }
}

element pop(StackType* s) {
    if (is_empty(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack Blank Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else {
        return s->data[(s->top)--];
    }
}

element peek(StackType* s) {
    if (is_empty(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack Blank Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else {
        return s->data[s->top];
    }
}

int check_matching(const char* in) {
    StackType s;
    char ch, open_ch;
    int n = strlen(in);
    init_stack(&s);

    int fail_pos[MAX_STACK_SIZE] = { 0, };
    int fail_cnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ch = in[i];

        if (ch == ' ') {
            continue;
        }

        switch (ch) {
        case '(': case '[': case '{':
            push(&s, ch);
            break;

        case ')': case ']': case '}':
            if (is_empty(&s)) {
                fail_pos[fail_cnt++] = i;
                break;
            }

            else {
                open_ch = pop(&s);

                if ((open_ch == '(' && ch != ')') || (open_ch == '[' && ch != ']') || (open_ch == '{' && ch != '}')) {
                    fail_pos[fail_cnt++] = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    while (!is_empty(&s)) {
        fail_pos[fail_cnt++] = pop(&s);
    }

    if (fail_cnt > 0) {
        printf("%s : Failed ", in);

        for (int i = 0; i < fail_cnt; i++) {
            if (fail_pos[i] >= strlen(in)) {
                printf("%d ", strlen(in));
            }
            
            else {
                printf("%d ", fail_pos[i] + 1);
            }
        }

        printf("\n");

        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char* expr = "A(x) = 24.5 * (x + func(x, y)) * (r * r * 3.14  / [7 % 10 * sqrt(25)];";

    if (check_matching(expr) == 1) {
        printf("%s : Complete\n", expr);
    }

    return 0;

    // A(x) = 24.5 * (x + func(x, y)) * (r * r * 3.14) / [7 % 10 * sqrt(25)]
}
```

**Output**

> A(x) = 24.5 * (x + func(x, y)) * (r * r * 3.14  / [7 % 10 * sqrt(25)]; : Failed 41

**Expected**

> A(x) = 24.5 * (x + func(x, y)) * (r * r * 3.14  / [7 % 10 * sqrt(25)]; : Failed 34

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your program and did a bit of debugging.  Actually, at issue is not that the program value of "41" being printed out has anything to do with the counter variable ("i").  Rather, the value of "41" is derived due to the fact that when the data element is popped off of the stack structure, what is being returned is the ASCII value of the opening parenthesis character, "(", which is the value of "40".  In adding a bit of additional detail to the printed output, this is what was printed at the terminal.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Formula/bin/Release$ ./Formula 
A(x) = 24.5 * (x + func(x, y)) * (r * r * 3.14  / [7 % 10 * sqrt(25)]; : Failed 41  aka character: (
```

In trying out some possible solutions, the main thing was that as opening formula control characters are found, their position needs to be stored along with character itself.  With that in mind, here are some of the refactored bits to the program to accommodate and use that information.

First off, an additional array was added to the stack structure.

```
typedef struct {
    element data[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int pos[MAX_STACK_SIZE];            /* Add this array to track position of the opening character */
    int top;
}StackType;
```

To accommodate saving that positional information during testing, the "push" function was revised to accept and store the positional data.

```
void push(StackType* s, element item, int pox) {
    if (is_full(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack Flow Error\n");
        return;
    }

    else {
        s->data[++(s->top)] = item;
        s->pos[s->top] = pox;           /* Store the position of the opening character */
    }
}
```

Next, a clone of the "pop" function was made for later use in returning the position of the character in question as opposed to returning the character value.

```
int popx(StackType* s) {
    int x = 0;
    if (is_empty(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack Blank Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else {
        x = s->pos[s->top];             /* Retrieve the character position value*/
        s->top--;
        return x;                       /* Return the associated character location */
    }
}
```

Function "pop" was left as is since it still has its usage in the testing process.

With the "push" function requiring the character position as well, the block of code utilizing this function was revised to include the positional value in the call.

```
        switch (ch) {
        case '(': case '[': case '{':
            push(&s, ch, i);            /* Include the position of the character in the function call */
            break;
```

Finally, in lieu of calling the "pop" function within the final "while" loop test, function "popx" is called instead to acquire the position any opening control characters not having a corresponding closing character.

```
    while (!is_empty(&s)) {
        fail_pos[fail_cnt++] = popx(&s);    /* Use the cloned function to return the character's position and not the character's equivalent integer value */
    }
```

With these tweaks, following was the terminal output when testing the statement.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Formula/bin/Release$ ./Formula 
A(x) = 24.5 * (x + func(x, y)) * (r * r * 3.14  / [7 % 10 * sqrt(25)]; : Failed 34
```

There might be some other subtle issues to be checked, which is why I concur with the good comments regarding utilizing a debugger utility as well.  Give this bit of refactoring a try and see if it meets the needs of your project.